#  Use another user's .vimrc and .vim/

Tags: linux, vim, root

I know that I can `:source /path/to/some/.vimrc` to load my user's `.vimrc` when running as root, but how can I use the entire `.vim/` directory as well? Is there a startup option for using `/home/user/.vim/` that I can set up as an alias?

And where in the fine manual would I have found this information if I had know what to look for. A simple `:help .vim` or `:help .vimrc` did not find the information regarding using the entire `.vim/` direcotry (`-U` is only for the `.vim` file).

Thanks.

Comment: `:help vimruntime` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the environment variable [`VIMINIT`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc) to point to the right `.vimrc` and [`VIMRUNTIME`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#$VIMRUNTIME) to point to the right `.vim`-directory. you can do this via `env`:

```
$> env VIMINIT=/home/user/.vimrc VIMRUNTIME=/home/user/.vim/ vim

$> VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC = expand('\''~user'\'') . '\''/.vimrc'\''|source $MYVIMRC' vim -c 'set runtimepath=~user/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~user/.vim/after'
```

as always: if thats too long to type, create a shell-function or a shell-alias.

to read more about how `vim` launches and what happens behind the scenes, read [`:help initialization`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization).

Comment: Thank you akira! This is exactly what I need, and thank you for the man page reference.

Comment: `VIMINIT` shouldn't be used like this

Answer (score 16):

It seems that `VIMINIT` and `VIMRUNTIME` are not used as akira said.

**`VIMINIT`** is used as an Ex command, so `VIMINIT=/home/user/.vimrc` would try a search and give an errror like:

```
search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP
Error detected while processing VIMINIT:
E486: Pattern not found: home
```

**`VIMRUNTIME`** normally point to the location where vim's basic support files is installed, like `/usr/share/vim/vim73`, so if it's redirected to /home/user/.vim, vim would lost many basic functions unless your vim is just installed to /home/usr/.vim.

---

According to `:help -u` and `:help vimrc`, **`-u vimrc`** option can specify the `.vimrc` file but will skip most other initialization files, like system vimrc, eg. `/etc/vimrc`. If the specified vimrc file does almost all jobs, then the shortcomming, if called this, is trivial.

According to `:help runtimepath`, pathes of **`runtimepath`** will be searched for support files, so we can prepend `/home/user/.vim` and append `/home/user/.vim/after` to `runtimepath` before soucing vimrc file using `--cmd` options at startup.

To sum up, we can set up this alias to use ~/.vimrc and ~/vim:

```
alias vim='vim --cmd "set runtimepath^=/home/user/.vim" \
               --cmd "set runtimepath+=/home/user/.vim/after" \
               -u /home/user/.vimrc'
```

---

ps. Alternatively, two simple symbolic links may also work for you.

```
mv /root/.vimrc{,.bak}
mv /root/.vim{,.bak}
ln -s /home/user/.vimrc /root/
ln -s /home/user/.vim /root/
```

Comment: I've been searching for this solution for quite sometime and this is the most definitive answer I have come across.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I had the exact problem you had with the E486 error. But your answer got me thinking : wouldn't it be possible to set `VIMINIT=":source /home/user/.vimrc"` and just be done with it? At least, it seems to work for me...

Comment: Even better, you can modify the runtimepath as you indicated in the same command : `VIMINIT=":set runtimepath^=/home/user.vim|:source /home/user/.vimrc"`. It works like a charm for me! :)

Comment: @user43791 your method works like a charm for me as well! :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best solution ever.

```
export MYVIMRC="/xxx/.vimrc"
export VIMINIT=":set runtimepath+=/xxx/.vim|:source $MYVIMRC"
```

where `xxx` is the customized path.